# Change Text function and then return

Tags: javascript

Okay so basicly I set out a javascript code that changes the text on click, but I have a problem when it comes on clicking again I want it to return again to the same state as before the change. I also tried the return function but I seem to do something wrong!

HTML:

```
<h5><div id="open">Concept Art -</div></h5>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#open").click(function(){
        $("#gallery3").toggle();
        $("#open").text("Concept Art +")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a data attribute and check it's status:

HTML

```
<h5><div id="open" data-state="open">Concept Art -</div></h5>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#open").click(function () {

    // cache the selector
    var $this = $(this);

    $("#gallery3").toggle();
    if ($this.data('state') === 'open') {
      $this.text("Concept Art -")
      $this.data('state', 'closed');
    } else {
      $this.text("Concept Art +")
      $this.data('state', 'open');
    }
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PhSLd/1/)

Comment: Thanks that really solved the problem. I'm pretty new to that stuff. I found one solution and then i had my self a problem! :) Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Just replace:

```
$("#open").text("Concept Art +")
```

with:

```
var mytext = $("#open").text()=='Concept art +' ? 'Concept art -' : 'Concept art +';
$("#open").text(mytext);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything that changes it back.

`$("#open").text("Concept Art +")` changes the text to have a '+' symbol, but you don't have anything to change it back to a '-'

You could try adding some `if` logic to check if there's a '-' or '+' present.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#open').toggle(function() {
        $(this).text('Concept Art +');
    }, function() {
        $(this).text('Concept Art -');
    });
});
```